# Is there a way to compare each list item to another list of exeptions?

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists with strings. I need to compare each item in the first list to list of exeptions in the other list and replace items in the first list with `' '` if there is the same item in two lists. List of exeptions is in the `.txt` document. I've tried to make some code but it seems to work only with string list written in actual vs code.

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()
with open('exeptions.txt') as f:
    c = f.read().splitlines()
if c != []:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == 'exeption':
            a[i] = ' '
```

Example of txt files:

- `input.txt` - `['a', 'b']`
- `exeptions.txt` - `['b']`
- `end goal` - `['a', ' ']`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and try to break the problem down into logical steps and *focus* on a *specific* question. Where exactly are you stuck? For example, can you write code that checks whether a specific item is in the exceptions list? Does the code for reading the files work properly? (Do you actually need to get the input from files, and write output to a file?) "ive tried to make some code but it seems to work only with string list written in actual vs code." I can't understand what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: First off, is this question about how to solve the problem? Or is it about fixing existing code? Choose one of those. If the question should be about how to solve the problem, then identify steps and figure out exactly what you need help with. Make sure that you can show exact input and exact expected output for that step. If it's about fixing the code, then please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ first and at least figure out where the problem is; then try to make a [mre] and explain how the behaviour of that code is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice and also info on how to ask and debug. I'm sorry that i didn't ask correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i,thing in enumerate(a):
    if thing in b:
        a[i] = ''
```

If the empty string placeholder is not necessary then you could use a set

```
a = list(set(a).difference(b))
```